# How to build a project without make (bare shell script)?

Tags: shell, makefile

I heard that back in the old days (or maybe not so old), before the `make` utility was included in Unix, people used to write shell script to "make" and "install" their software.

Consider a project with: 2 source files `main.c` and `util.c`, a header `util.h` that uses the OpenGL library and needs to run on Ubuntu.

(Ubuntu and OpenGL are used just for the sake of being specific)

What would such a script actually need to do? Where can I find an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to imagine why anyone would want to revisit "the bad old days" before `make`, but it's actually not too difficult for a simple project.  So given your particular example, a shell script to compile might look like this:

```
gcc -Wall -c main.c -o main.o -lglut -lglm 
gcc -Wall -c util.c -o util.o -lglut -lglm
gcc -Wall main.o util.o -o main -lglut -lglm
```

What it does is to simply run through the entire "recipe" to build the project every time.  The advantage is that, if the source code is all correct, it should result in an executable.  The considerable disadvantages are that

- if any step fails, so will subsequent steps that rely on the failed step
- everything is rebuilt every time, wasting a lot of time
- compile and link flags are all embedded into the script and hard to change
- this approach has little hope of cross-platform compatibility

One can tinker with the basic shell script to improve on various aspects of this.  Then, when that proves inadequate, one could write a program to do these things better.  At that point, in essence, you will have re-invented `make`.

Comment: What exactly are the portability issues? Like the inability to run a bash script on windows, or something more delicate?

Comment: The reasons for inventing and using `make` are the above; portability has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Actually, portability is a factor.  It is common within a `makefile` to incorporate, say, different linker flags for different platforms, such as BSD and Linux and Solaris.  One *could* do the same thing with scripts, but less easily.  Also, one can often rely on implicit rules so that `make util.o` will invoke the correct compiler and use the correct flags on that platform even in the absence of any `makefile`.